# Reading value from xls file but numeric value are not read properly

Tags: excel, go, xls

Numeric value from xls file are not reading properly but the string values are fine

```
file, _ := xls.Open("test.xls", "utf-8")

    sheet := file.GetSheet(0)
    for r := 0; r <= (int(sheet.MaxRow)); r++ {
      row := sheet.Row(r)
      log.Println("column with numeric value: ", row.Col(0))
      log.Println("column with string value: ", row.Col(1))
    }
```

**test.xls:**

```
123 | test

456 | testing
```

**output:**

```
column with numeric value: @

column with string value: test

column with numeric value: @

column with string value: testing
```

How can I get numeric value correctly?

Comment: You are using [extrame/xls](https://github.com/extrame/xls)?

Comment: Yes github.com/extrame/xls

Comment: There is no issue in the code and it is printing numerical values correctly, I believe that the problem is with the xls file format. Maybe saving it again in the correct format will solve the issue. Open the xls file in Excel and then save it as  `File -> Save as -> Excel 97- 2003 (Save as type)`, after this try this code again.

Comment: My file format is Excel 97- 2003 still its not reading int value correctly

Comment: @Nandini Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 18.04,I can open file and print content of second column

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/extrame/xls"
    "log"
)


func main() {
if xlFile, err := xls.Open("test.xls", "utf-8"); err == nil {
    for i := 0; i < xlFile.NumSheets(); i++ {
        sheet := xlFile.GetSheet(i)
        fmt.Println(sheet.Name)
        for r := 0; r <= (int(sheet.MaxRow)); r++ {
                row := sheet.Row(r)
                log.Println("column ", row.Col(1))
        }
    }
}
```

}

Pay special attention on Col(1) indexing.

Output

```
Sheet1
2019/04/03 14:28:29 column  test
2019/04/03 14:28:29 column  testi
2019/04/03 14:28:29 column  testing
```

But for numerical column I got this

```
Sheet1
2019/04/03 14:27:46 column  General
2019/04/03 14:27:46 column  General
2019/04/03 14:27:46 column  General
```

I saved the same file as xlsx. This works with tealeg/xlsx package

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/tealeg/xlsx"
)

func main() {
    excelFileName := "test.xlsx"
    xlFile, err := xlsx.OpenFile(excelFileName)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("can not open file!!!", err)
    return
    }
    for _, sheet := range xlFile.Sheets {
        for _, row := range sheet.Rows {
            for _, cell := range row.Cells {
                text := cell.String()
                fmt.Println(text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
123
test
788
456
testi
999
789
testing
100
```

Comment: But my numeric value output is @